# Different gas costs for token transfer on Fantom network

Tags: gas, fantom

Can someone explain why the same WFTM transfer costs one time 38k and another time 23k gas?

Here are the two transactions:

https://ftmscan.com/tx/0xfaf2b8757f2c1d90a7b58df7f4cbd4022062855ca77095ac705ace91a5f3cf35

https://ftmscan.com/tx/0x1b88ea94d5fb57d7f07a45402090fbdd0b47017e49b2632dc78ea0e860cc0e57

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the gas metering of storage changes.

When you transfer a token, the balance sheet inside the token contract is updated. This means you need to adjust the balance of the sender and the receiver.

When a storage slot was originally `0` and is changed to a non-zero value, you need to pay 20k gas. Otherwise you pay 5k gas. And you change the value from non-zero to zero you get a gas refund at the end of transaction of 15k gas.

Looking at the second link you shared you can see that `0x3099e12ca83c51e9b82ea6c5a08723aed4912068` transferred all tokens available, therefore setting the balance of that account to zero. This triggered the gas refund of 15k gas, which is the difference in gas costs.

Comment: Many thanks that sounds interesting.